# Linking UIView subclass and ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIView subclass that I want to appear on an xib created from a ViewController class. 
My UIView class is called Tag and the other ViewController

```
// Tag.h

UIView *view;

// Tag.m 

if (self) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewController" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.view];
}
return self;
```

Am I close? It doesn't seem to be linking

Comment: `self.view` is already in use. What class did you use in the nib? Load it into `MyClass subview`. Check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW8

Comment: Please share more code and information. Tag is a subclass of UIView. You sould be able to place a UIView in IB. In the view controller's .h file declare an IBOutlet property of the type Tag. Then you shoudl be able to link that to the UIView representation in IB. What of these have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't declare my class in ViewController.h  By IB property do you mean @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *Tag;

Comment: whuch is your subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass :MyView

.h

```
interface MyView : UIView
@end
```

To add in view controller : MainViewController

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyView.h"
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet  MyView *viewObj;
@end
```

in Xib

[image]
Connect the outlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from xib file write Tag on Class field

[image]

Comment: Sorry not sure I was clear and now am still a bit confused. I have a ViewController.h and .m that has an xib. I would like to connect my UIView subclass "Tag" to it. So in my ViewController. h I have :@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *tagview;